# Best way to provide Function argument

Tags: c++

I have an Api which takes two struct as an arguments

```
struct bundle{
int a;
int b;
int c;
};

void func(const bundle& startBundle, const bundle& endBundle);
```

Also I have to write another API which has same requirement but instead of int a in bundle struct it should be double.

I can write 2 structs(1 for int and 1 for double) but it seems not good and if I am use the struct , the functions have too many arguments(3 agruments for start and 3 agruments for end). 
Please suggest some correct way of doing this problem.

Also If I have to use default argument for endBundle, How can I use it?

Answer (score 8):

You could make `bundle` a template:

```
template <typename T>
struct bundle {
    T a;
    T b;
    T c;
};

void func(const bundle<int>& startBundle, const bundle<int>& endBundle);
```

Or you could use `std::array`:

```
using IntBundle = std::array<int, 3>;
using DoubleBundle = std::array<double, 3>;
void func(const IntBundle& startBundle, const IntBundle& endBundle);
```

If you want different types in the same bundle, you could use `std::tuple`:

```
using IntBundle = std::tuple<int,int,int>;
using OtherBundle = std::tuple<float,int,int>;
```

Or make `bundle` take three template arguments:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct bundle {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
};
```

Comment: In case of std::array<double, 3> , all 3 arguments will be double, but I need only 1st agrument to be double.

Comment: @anujgupta Ah, I didn't catch that bit. See my edit.